# Old backup data not shown in GAE sql instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

How to restore from an google cloud sql instance backup data which was 90 days old. As for now, GAE clould sql instance page shows only the last 7 backups not the full list of backups. Is there any way to get the old backup to restore?

[image]

I want the backup made on July 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backups are only kept for 7 days.

Comment: No. As described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery/backups), automated backups are kept for 7 days. For Second Generation instances, you are able to create manual backups as well.